# Read Value of Hidden Column in JQuery

Tags: jquery, datatables

I need to hide a column on the table, but after that I cannot read selected row's hidden column value.

```
 dtTable = $('#lookupTable').DataTable({
       "columnDefs": [
           {
               "targets": [ 0 ],
               "visible": false,
               "searchable": false               
           }
        ],  

        aaData: data,
        aoColumns: cols,
        paging: false,
        scrollCollapse: true,
        destroy: true

    });
```

as you see the first column is hidden now. And I am trying to read the column value with that code

```
    selectedIndex = $(this).find('td:eq(0)').text();
```

if i delete <"visible": false> from the code i can read the first column's value, but if it is hidden it gives me second column value.

I tired to change "witdh" property but it didnt work..

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The CSS selector wont work, because `"visible": false` in your `columnDefs` does not mean that the column gets the equivalent `display: none;` style property in the markup.

Instead, you'll have to use the DataTables API to get the data in the hidden column.

The function `fnGetData` will do the trick. It returns the text data in the cell that is passed as an argument to the function.

Heres the example from the documentation

```
oTable.$('td').click( function () {
    var sData = oTable.fnGetData( this );
    alert( 'The cell clicked on had the value of '+sData );
});
```

In your case, the column is hidden, thus you'll have to combine it with a second API call. Say that you click the row with the hidden first column, you can combine the `fnGetData` with the `fnGetPosition` function.

```
var position = dtTable.fnGetPosition(this);
var hiddenColumnValue = dtTable.fnGetData(position)[0];
```

Check the documentation, it has some great examples.

[fnGetData()](http://datatables.net/api#fnGetData)

[fnGetPosition()](http://datatables.net/api#fnGetPosition)

This is the working code

```
  $('#lookupTable tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {

        selectedIndex = dtTable.row(this).data()[0];   
 });
```

Comment: Thank you so much, i search fnGetData function but it was old one, so and i found  table.row(..) so it works.. this is my code..   $('#lookupTable tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {
        // get the first value from cell

  
        selectedIndex = dtTable.row(this).data()[0];       });

Comment: this wok, but for pagination index would be changed and need to consider page index also

Comment: Daniel B - You are my hero!  +1 to both question and answer.  Thank you.

Answer (score 9):

Go through the dataTables API and you have multiple ways to retrieve data from hidden columns the correct way. For example you can use [**`cells`**](https://datatables.net/reference/type/cell-selector). As you see in the link you can use all kind of selectors with `cells`, like a jQuery selector.

Here a very simple example that logs out the values of the first column that has been hidden :

```
var dtTable = $('#example').DataTable()  

dtTable.columns([0,1,2]).visible(false);

for (var i=0;i<10;i++) {
    console.log(dtTable.cells({ row: i, column: 0 }).data()[0]);
}
```

**http://jsfiddle.net/oumtdd6k/**

It cannot be emphasized enough : *Always go through the API, do not try to use traditional jQuery on an initialised dataTable*!!

In this case the reason is obvious : jQuery can only access elements that actually is in the DOM. When you hide columns in dataTables they are not hidden as in `display: none`, they are simply not rendered!

Comment: Thank your for your answer. I tried the code but it always give from 0 to 9 even I change the order. But it is ok, the other answer works for me

Comment: @unbalanced - yes, because of the for-loop going from 0-9 :) The selector in this case is `{ row : <index>, column : 0 }` - great you got it to work!

Answer (score 3):

The correct answer is pretty old. So, if the correct answer does not work out for you. Please try this method :

```
selectedIndex = dtTable.row(this).data();
```

This code will return the raw json object which was fetched for this row. something like :

```
{
   "modify":"false",
   "lastModify":"Tuesday",
   "name":"abc",
   "DT_RowId":"row_1",
   "fileID":"0bde976"
}
```

To get the "fileID" you just need to :

```
alert("ID = "+selectedIndex.fileID);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var dtTable = $('#test').DataTable()
```

```js
      $('#test tbody').on('click', 'tr td .fa-pencil', function (e) {
                    ID = (dtTable.row($(this).closest('tr')).data().Id);
});
```

`

Comment: You should describe your answer or comment your code

Answer (score 0):

Another Soultion Is Add Css Class ID Fiekd Visbilety hideen And $(this).find('td:eq(0)').text();  Retrive The value..

Comment: Please try to format you answer (https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) to make it easier to understand and also add some explanation.

Answer (score 0):

```
var table= $('#tablename').DataTable();

var hiddenColumnData1 = table.row('#trIdName').data()[1];
var hiddenColumnData2 = table.row('#trIdName').data()[2];

console.log("First Hidden Column Data of 'trIdName' : "+hiddenColumnData1) 
console.log("Second Hidden Column Data of 'trIdName' : "+hiddenColumnData1)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

Traditional jquery wont work on datatable , you have to use API defined methods to get the value. In my case this worked fine to get hidden column value on button click in each row  -

```
$(function () {
       var t = $('#mytableid').DataTable({
            "columnDefs": [{
                "searchable": false,
                "orderable": false,
                "visible":false,
                "targets": [0]
            }]
        });

        $('#mytableid').on('click', '.btnClass', function () {
            var currentRow = $(this).closest("tr");
            var columnvalue = t.row(currentRow).data()[0];
            console.log(columnvalue);
        });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding to this as this is old, and none of the answers had the quick, clean jquery format I was used to. You can use the traditional jquery selectors even if the objects you are trying to access are not currently rendered in the DOM, i.e. hidden or on another page, by doing it as a method of the Datatable.
So in your case:

```
dtable.$("yourJQuerySelector")
```

This will select the element as you are used to and worked for my case.